# Outlining text in one cell drawing from multiple sources

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with the creation of a uniform data label to be used in a graph in Excel.

The label draws from multiple sources with different digit lengths in each cell and in each row.

If I construct the label using for example: `=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1`, The outlining is off:

```
=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1

Jim Litle 27        
Dillan South 35
```

when this is required:

```
Jim    Litle  27                    
Dillan South  35
```

I thought of having the spaces vary by using the 'Space()' function in VBA and subtracting from that the digit count by using the LEN() function something to the tune of this:

```
=A1&Space(25-LEN(A1))&A2&Space(25-LEN(A2)&A3
```

However the Space() function only seems to work in VBA. I tried to create the following custom function but could not manage to make it work:

```
Function LABEL() As String

    Dim Name As String
    Dim Surname As String
    Dim Age As Variant
       
    LABEL =(Name,space(25-LEN(Name),Surname,space(25-LEN(Surname),Age)
    
End Function
```

Is there an easier way to construct the label?

Comment: [`REPT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rept-function-04c4d778-e712-43b4-9c15-d656582bb061) can be used in formulas

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As per Chris Neilsen's suggestion below, do the following and change the font in `D1` and `D2` to (for example) *Lucinda Console* and see the result!

I understand what you’re trying to achieve, however, it’s not possible with the approach you are taking.  The reason for this is that – using @chris neilsen’s advice – the `REPT` Function will give you a correct number of spaces between each of the text strings, but the text strings themselves consist of letters that are *themselves of different widths*.

To demonstrate what I’m saying, and assuming the text cells are in `A1`, `B1` and `C1` (and in `A2`, `B2` and `C2`), enter the following formula into cell `D1` (and copy it down to cell `D2`):

`=A1&REPT(CHAR(32),(25-LEN(A1)))&B1&REPT(CHAR(32),(25-LEN(B1)))&C1`

You’ll see that the text doesn’t align exactly as you would want it.  Now change the capital “D” of “Dillan” to capital “I” and see the difference one *narrower* letter makes.

I’m not sure there’s a workaround in VBA either, but happy to be corrected.

Comment: This kind of approach requires use of a proportionally spaced font, where each character is the same width